# How to get unique pairs in SQL where no part of the pair is present in other pairs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with event data whose schema is similar to the screenshot shown below.

[image]

Basically there are some events that are randomly flagged as 0 or 1.

What I want to do is find events with `flag=0` that happened within 30 seconds of event with `flag=1`

I figured how to do that by doing a cross join table with itself and then filtering out event combinations with the below query

```
select *
from input_tbl t1, input_tbl t2
where abs(timestamp_diff(t1.eventTs,t2.eventTs,seconds)<=30
```

But the issues here is for the eventId=6324, both 5485 and 7516 are eligible events within 30 seconds and similarly for 8224, 5485 happened within 30 seconds.

What I want is no `flag=0` event to repeat more than once. So in this particular case event `6324 will be paired with 7516 and 8224 will be paired with 5485`

Answer (score 0):

Try window function

```
select *
from (
    select t1.*, t2.*, row_number() over(partition by t1.eventTs order by t2.eventTs) rn
    from input_tbl t1
    join input_tbl t2
      on t1.flag=1 and t2.flag=0  
       and timestamp_diff(t1.eventTs,t2.eventTs,seconds) between 0 and 30
) t 
where rn=1
```

Comment: In this particular instance it would work but I am dealing with 1000's of such cases with almost each timestamp. So how to ensure that t2.eventId doesn't repeat with another t1.event?

Comment: Suppose the table contains  two flag=1 events and only one flag=0 event matching both flag=1 events. What is the desired output?

Comment: In that case the one of those events should have null/no pair. It can be either one. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Looks like you need recursion.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is find events with flag=0 that happened within 30 seconds of event with flag=1

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.* except (cnt_1)
from (select t.*,
             countif(flag = 1) over (order by timestamp_seconds(eventts)
                                     range between -30 and current row
                                    ) as cnt_1
      from t
     ) t
where flag = 0 and cnt_1 > 0;
```

This counts the number of "1" flags in the previous 30 seconds.  The outer query filters when the flag is available.